# Bootstrap Dialog CSS Causing Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, whmcs

I m having a problem with Bootstrap Dialog library designed to assist in modal windows.
I would like to use the library in WHMCS but it seems as though the files I need to include break the template.

As indicated by the examples I included:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

But as soon as I do this the template breaks. It throws litterally everything out of place, including the menus and images in WHMCS. **But the popup I excecute does show**.

If I remove the `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` the template does go back to normal, but then the command that I call to show the dialog does nothing. I cannot see a response in the console, nor do I see anything happen in the browser anymore.

What could be the cause & a possible solution to this issue?

Is there a way to use this library and/or another similar library?

I would love any and all advice in this matter.

Bootstrap Dialog: https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Comment: Bootstrap's dialogs depend on a lot of Bootstrap's classes. It's not really a standalone library. It's not shocking that you can't just drop it into another software product without issues.

Comment: Ok @ceejayoz do you have any suggestions though?